# Can't mount /system read-write

Tags: mount, make, mkdir

When I make install reaver in *termux* the following error occurs:

```
./install.sh -D -m 755 wash /usr/local/bin/wash
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr’: Read-only file system
make: *** [Makefile:140: install] Error 1
```

I tried to `mount -o remount,rw /system`:

```
mount: '/system' not in /proc/mounts
```

I also tried `mount -o rw,remount /`:

```
mount: '/dev/block/platform/soc/7824900.sdhci/by-name/system' not user mountable in fstab
```

None of them helped.

Comment: Do you have root privileges?

Comment: If you are wanting to remount `/usr` as read/write, then why are you trying to remount `/system` and `/`?! Also, is there a _reason_ your `/usr` partition is mounted read-only (like was there a power outage and the disk now has errors on it?)?  You need root privileges to remount `/usr`.

Comment: @Rayleigh, of course.

Comment: @Kusalananda, ok, I will try it

Comment: @Kusalananda, `mount: '/usr' not in /proc/mounts`

Comment: Well, then your `/usr` is part of the `/` mount, which appears to be read-only for some odd reason. So you _might_ want to try that last command in the question as root, or you might want to reboot and let the startup procedures check the disk.  If `/` is mounted read-only, that usually means `fsck` detected issues with the disk.  I'm no Linux user though, so I only speak with partial knowledge.

Comment: (referring to a delete comment:) I was just going to ask what the tag [tag:tmux] had to do with your question. Did you use that tag because it was closest in spelling to "termux"? I know nothing of Android. You should mention in the question what type of Unix you are using.

Comment: @Kusalananda, what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:

```
tsudo mount -o remount,rw /
```

*tsudo it's sudo for termux

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to treat your Termux environment as a regular Unix environment, but it's not. When you start a Termux shell, you're running as a non-root user. You can't install things into Android system directories.

Take a look at existing commands provided by Termux:

```
$ which ls
/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/ls
```

If you want to build and install your own software, you'll need to arrange to install it into the same path prefix.  If you're build software that uses `autoconf`, that might look something like:

```
./configure --prefix=/data/data/com.termux/files/usr
```

If your software uses some other build configuration mechanism, you'll need to figure out what to do.

Comment: They may possibly want to use `/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/local` as prefix.